# Running Ghost on Raspberry PI getting error

Tags: server

I am new to this stackexchange so sorry if my question should be wrong here and belongs to another stackexchange. Also I am a raspberry pi newbie with just basic skills of using the console.

I have the Rapsberry Pi and I am trying to use it as a server for a ghost blog. I used the following tutorial to set it up, tough I skipped the first step since I don't want to run the OS from an USB stick. I run it from an SD card: 
http://jamiegoodwin.co.uk/how-to-run-ghost-effectively-from-a-raspberry-pi/

To give yo an insight about my environment:
The raspberry Pi is connected to the internet via WLAN. It is connected to my Apple Time capsule which is a bridge to my fritzbox. In the fritzbox I gave the Raspberry Pis Mac address a static IP of 192.168.178.29. In the Raspberry I have automatic IP assignment activated so it now should always get the IP 192.168.178.29 from my fritzbox. 
I made an CloudFlare account and it is now automatically getting the external ip address of my local network (checked IP of fritzbox with CloudFlare and it updates automatically). I set the name server of my name cheap url "tapemachine.org" to the name servers of CloudFlare. I used DNS on CloudFlare to point tapemachine.org to the automatic updated IP address of my fritzbox. (Type A)
I am using my Macbook to control the Raspberry Pi via a ssh connection over terminal.
I Installed node.js, ghost, forever (running), varnish. I changed the production url in the ghost config file to "tapemachine.org" and the production IP address to 192.168.178.29:80 I also updated varnish config file with the same IP.

Problem: Now every time I write "tapemachine.org" (name of my future ghost blog) into the browser of I get a 523 error origin is unreachable from cloudflare. Maybe you could try to input the URL to see the same error.

Can you Image whats the problem why the connection between cloud flare and the origin is not working?

Thank you so much and sorry for the wall of text! Please tell me if you need some code citing of my config files.

Comment: Is this for Ghost the cloning tool? Or something else?

Comment: Ghost blogging: https://ghost.org, It is the new CMS from he creator of wordpress optimised for blogging without all the features or wordpress to keep it simple. It runs on node.js the wrapped js from google chrome.